# Showing $\big( \frac{a}{n\bar{x}}, \frac{b}{n\bar{x}} \big)$ is an exact confidence interval for a gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, gamma-function

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$
This implies that $Y=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ has a gamma distribution with parameters $(\lambda,n)$

Can anyone help me show that 
$$\left( \frac{a}{n\bar{x}}, \frac{b}{n\bar{x}} \right)$$
Is an exact $95$% central confidence interval for $\lambda$ if

$$\int_0^a \frac{y^{n-1}e^{-y}\;dy}{\Gamma(n)}= \int_b^\infty \frac{y^{n-1}e^{-y}\;dy}{\Gamma(n)}= 0.025$$

Here is what I have so far. Basically i've been trying to construct anything to help use those given integrals

$$P\left(\frac{a}{n\bar{x}}<Y<\frac{b}{n\bar{x}}\right)=P\left(Y<\frac{a}{n\bar{x}}\right)+P\left(Y<\frac{b}{n\bar{x}}\right)-1$$

$$=\lambda^{-n}\int_0^\frac{a}{n\bar{x}} \frac{y^{n-1}e^{-y/\lambda}\;dy}{\Gamma(n)}+\lambda^{-n}\int_0^\frac{b}{n\bar{x}} \frac{y^{n-1}e^{-y/\lambda}\;dy}{\Gamma(n)}-1$$

Which is where I get stuck as this doesn't really look salvagable.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote
$$P\left(\frac{a}{n\bar{x}}<Y<\frac{b}{n\bar{x}}\right).$$
But what you need is
$$P\left(\frac{a}{n\bar{X}}<\lambda<\frac{b}{n\bar{X}}\right) = 0.95.\tag{1}$$
I've set $\bar X$ in capital since it's a random variable.  One *must* remember what is random and what is not random in this kind of problem.  To say that $a/(n\bar X)$ is "random" in effect means that if you take another sample, the value of that expression will change.  $\lambda$ on the other hand is not random since it will remain the same if another sample is taken.

(1) is equivalent to
$$
P\left(\frac a\lambda < n\bar X < \frac b\lambda\right) = 0.95,
$$
or
$$
P\left(\frac a\lambda < Y < \frac b\lambda\right) = 0.95 \tag{2}
$$
Here is an ambiguity in the question: does "exponential with parameter $\lambda$" mean having density proportional to $y\mapsto e^{-\lambda y}$ or does it mean $y\mapsto e^{-y/\lambda}$?  Since (2) is equivalent to
$$
P\left(a < \lambda Y < b\right) = 0.95,
$$
I take it to mean $\lambda Y$ has a gamma distribution with parameter $1$ in place of $\lambda$, so the density of the exponential is proportional to $y\mapsto e^{-\lambda y}$, i.e. $\lambda$ is an intensity parameter rather than a scale parameter.

So
$$
P(X_i > c) = \int_c^\infty e^{-\lambda u} (\lambda \; du) = \int_{\lambda c}^\infty e^{-y}\;dy,
$$
and so
$$
P(Y>c) = (X_1 + \cdots + X_n > c) = \int_{\lambda c}^\infty \frac{y^{n-1} e^{-y}}{\Gamma(n)} \; dy.
$$

Finally we have
$$
P\left( \frac a\lambda < Y < \frac b\lambda \right) = \int_{\lambda(a/\lambda)}^{\lambda(a/\lambda)} \cdots\cdots = \int_a^b \cdots\cdots.
$$

Comment: Thank you this is incredibly helpful! Thank you for being slow and clear in your answer, it made it very easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $E[X_i] = \lambda^{-1}$, $Y = \sum_i X_i = n\bar{X}$ is a Gamma random variable with mean $n\lambda^{-1}$ and density function
$$f_Y(y) = \lambda \frac{(\lambda y)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}\exp(-\lambda y)\mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}.$$
**Define** $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as the solutions to $F_Y(\alpha)=0.025$
and $F_Y(\beta) = 0.975$ so that 
$$P\{\alpha \leq Y \leq \beta\} = F_Y(\beta) - F_Y(\alpha) = 0.95$$
and note that
$$F_Y(\alpha) = \int_0^{\alpha} 
\lambda \frac{(\lambda y)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}\exp(-\lambda y) \mathrm dy
= \int_0^{\lambda\alpha} 
 \frac{t^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}\exp(-t) \mathrm dt$$ so that $a = \lambda \alpha$
and similarly $b = \lambda \beta$.  Verify for yourself that the following
bounds hold:
$$ \alpha < n\lambda^{-1} < \beta; ~~ a < n < b.$$

Now suppose that the value of $\lambda$ is unknown.
We observe the values of the $X_i$, compute the value
of $Y = \sum_i X_i = n\bar{X}$, and have $95\%$ confidence
that $Y$ is in the interval $[\alpha, \beta]$ whose end-points
are, unfortunately, unknown to us.  But, if we assume that
the *known* value of $Y$ is at the endpoint $\alpha = a/\lambda$, 
then we are in effect *estimating*
that the unknown value of $\lambda$ is $a/Y = a/n\bar{X}$
while if we assume that $Y$ is at the other endpoint 
$\beta = b/\lambda$, then we are 
in effect *estimating*
that the unknown value of $\lambda$ is $b/Y = b/n\bar{X}$.
More generally, if we simply assume that $Y$ *has* taken
on the expected value $n\lambda^{-1}$, we in effect estimate
the value of $\lambda$ as 
$$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{n}{Y} = \frac{n}{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}$$
which will be readily recognized as the maximum-likelihood
estimate of the parameter $\lambda$ of an exponential random variable $X$
based on $n$ independent observations of $X$.  But now we also
have a $95\%$ confidence interval for our estimate.

> If the sample mean is $\bar{X}$, then 
>   $\left(\frac{a}{n\bar{X}},\frac{b}{n\bar{X}}\right)$ is an exact  $95\%$
>   confidence interval for the unknown parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed answer, it was very helpful. I feel I know understand this